# Differences between Voldemort and Riak KV

Tags: nosql, key-value, riak, voldemort

I have read about these two databases. I am interested in some practical differences between them, but I couldn't find any. They are both AP Key-Value databases.

They are mostly compared only to relational databases, not to each other.

Has someone some experience with both of them? Is there some other difference except that Riak is more popular?

Thank you